# How to find and calculate common letters between words in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with some words in it and I want to compare 2 columns and count common letters between them.

For e.g I have:

```
data = {'Col_1' : ['Heaven', 'Jako', 'Sm', 'apizza'],
       'Col_2' : ['Heaven', 'Jakob', 'Smart', 'pizza']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

| Col_1  | Col_2  |
-------------------
| Heaven | Heaven |
| Jako   | Jakob  |
| Sm     | Smart  |
| apizza | pizza  |
```

And I want to have smth like that:

```
| Col_1  | Col_2  | Match                          | Count |
------------------------------------------------------------
| Heaven | Heaven | ['H', 'e', 'a', 'v', 'e', 'n'] | 6     |
| Jako   | Jakob  | ['J', 'a', 'k', 'o']           | 4     |
| Sm     | Smart  | ['S', 'm']                     | 2     |
| apizza | pizza  | []                             | 0     |
```

Comment: why is the last one having no match?

Comment: Because for me the order of the letters is important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with help of [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
from itertools import takewhile
df['Match'] = [[x for x,y in takewhile(lambda x: x[0]==x[1], zip(a,b))]
               for a,b in zip(df['Col_1'], df['Col_2'])]
df['Count'] = df['Match'].str.len()
```

output:

```
    Col_1   Col_2               Match  Count
0  Heaven  Heaven  [H, e, a, v, e, n]      6
1    Jako   Jakob        [J, a, k, o]      4
2      Sm   Smart              [S, m]      2
3  apizza   pizza                  []      0
```

*NB. the logic was no fully clear, so here this stops as soon as there is a mistmatch*

If you want to continue after a mistmatch (which doesn't seems to fit the "pizza" example):

```
df['Match'] = [[x for x,y in zip(a,b) if x==y]
               for a,b in zip(df['Col_1'], df['Col_2'])]
df['Count'] = df['Match'].str.len()
```

output:

```
    Col_1   Col_2               Match  Count
0  Heaven  Heaven  [H, e, a, v, e, n]      6
1    Jako   Jakob        [J, a, k, o]      4
2      Sm   Smart              [S, m]      2
3  apizza   pizza                 [z]      1
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a different route and used the `SequenceMatcher` from the underrated [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#) which is aimed at comparaisons between sequences.

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def common(a, b):
    s = SequenceMatcher(None, a, b)
    left, right = s.find_longest_match().a, s.find_longest_match().b
    if left != right:
        return []
    else: return list(a[left:s.find_longest_match().size])

df["Match"] = df.apply(lambda x : common(x[0], x[1]), axis=1)
df["Count"] = df["Match"].apply(len)
```

Results in:

```
0    [H, e, a, v, e, n]
1          [J, a, k, o]
2                [S, m]
3                    []
dtype: object
```

So what it does is take the two strings and compare them for the longest matches between them. The `a` attribute is the index at which the left hand side string starts to much and the `b` attribute is the right hand side equivalent. It also has a `size` attribute that tells us how long the match was.

If `a` and `b` are different, it means that they start matching a different places in the string which was against the rule here. Then we just keep the left hand side string and grab it until there is no match anymore.

The end `df` looks like this ofc:

```
    Col_1   Col_2               Match  Count
0  Heaven  Heaven  [H, e, a, v, e, n]      6
1    Jako   Jakob        [J, a, k, o]      4
2      Sm   Smart              [S, m]      2
3  apizza   pizza                  []      0
```